# Terse Method to Swap Lowest for Highest?

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, sorting, permutation

I have built a solution to swap the lowest values with the highest values in a list.

With

```
SeedRandom[987]
test = RandomSample@*Join @@ Range @@@ {{6, 10}, {56, 60}, {1, 5}, {-5, -1}}
```

> ```
> {-1, 2, 7, 8, 60, 57, 58, 10, 9, 4, -5, -3, 3, 59, 1, 5, -4, 6, -2, 56}
> ```

Then

```
swapPositions =
 PermutationReplace[
  Ordering@Ordering@test,
  With[{len = Length@test},
   Cycles@
    Transpose@{Range @@ {1, Floor[len/2]}, Reverse@*Range @@ {Ceiling[len/2] + 1, len}}
   ]
  ];

Sort[test][[swapPositions]]
```

> ```
> {56, 9, 4, 3, -5, -2, -3, 1, 2, 7, 60, 58, 8, -4, 10, 6, 59, 5, 57, -1}
> ```

The largest half of the numbers have had their positions swapped with lowest half of the numbers.

However, it feels too verbose and I think `Sort` might be expensive in this case. Is there a built-in function or more terse method to achieve this. Of course with no loss in speed. The actual case is for list of length 100000 and more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Permute[Sort @ #, Reverse @ Ordering @ #] & @ test
```

> {56, 9, 4, 3, -5, -2, -3, 1, 2, 7, 60, 58, 8, -4, 10, 6, 59, 5, 57, -1}

Also

```
Permute[test[[#]], Reverse @ #] & @ Ordering[test]
```

> {56, 9, 4, 3, -5, -2, -3, 1, 2, 7, 60, 58, 8, -4, 10, 6, 59, 5, 57, -1}

and

```
test[[Reverse @ #]][[Ordering @ #]] & @ Ordering[test]
```

> {56, 9, 4, 3, -5, -2, -3, 1, 2, 7, 60, 58, 8, -4, 10, 6, 59, 5, 57, -1}

Answer (score 17):

How about:

```
Module[{tmp = test},
    With[{ord=Ordering[tmp]},
        tmp[[ord]] = Reverse @ tmp[[ord]]];
    tmp
]
```

> {56, 9, 4, 3, -5, -2, -3, 1, 2, 7, 60, 58, 8, -4, 10, 6, 59, 5, 57, -1}

Comment: That is so obvious I want to cry.  Thanks (+1).

Answer (score 8):

This is equivalent to Carl's procedure, except that it uses one less scratch list:

```
With[{ord = Ordering[test]},
     test[[PermutationProduct[Reverse[ord], InversePermutation[ord]]]]]
   {56, 9, 4, 3, -5, -2, -3, 1, 2, 7, 60, 58, 8, -4, 10, 6, 59, 5, 57, -1}
```

Recall that `list[[perm]] = list` is equivalent to `list = list[[InversePermutation[perm]]]`, where `perm` is a permutation list. (The situation is equivalent to `list.pmat` being the same as `Transpose[pmat].list` if `pmat` is a permutation matrix.) You can then use `PermutationProduct[]` to compose successive permutations.

(This was supposed to be a comment, but it got too long.)

Comment: This solution doesn't copy the list so may be faster than Carl's. (+1).

Comment: FWIW, I consistently get {56, -2, 6, -4, 5, 1, 59, 3, -3, -5, 4, 9, 10, 58, 57, 60, 8, 7, 2,
-1}  from this.

Comment: @Rabbit, what version number of *Mathematica* is giving that result?

Comment: 11.3.0.0   (5944644, 2018030701) Win 10.  I did a trace, which might have had the needed info but I didn't catch it. Started w/ fresh kernel, & repeated, w/ same result.  Baffled.

Comment: @Rabbit, can you try with `With[{ord = Ordering[test]}, test[[PermutationProduct[InversePermutation[ord], Reverse[ord]]]]]`?

Comment: Bingo!  This will give me something to work on.  Thanks much.                           {56, 9, 4, 3, -5, -2, -3, 1, 2, 7, 60, 58, 8, -4, 10, 6, 59, 5, 57, -1}

Comment: Hmm, permutation products are noncommutative, so... I need to think why this is so.

Comment: At least on my machine, the questioner's original (very verbose) proposed solution is faster than any other proposal.  In order of presentation: 0.0000114366 v. 0.0000357762 v. 0.0000164219 (AbsoluteTiming in seconds).